# Intense distortion when rotating objects OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math

I have been trying to rotate a quad by making a view matrix and model matrix. I am using GLM to do this.

Here is the code for making the matrices:

```
glm::mat4 view = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), position);
view = view * glm::rotate(glm::radians(pitch), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

glm::mat4 model = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
```

Here is the vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

So this code is rotating the objects, but they get *very* distorted as they rotate and they rotate slower at the top and bottom of the screen. I tried to look up another way of doing this, but everything else showed nothing on the screen at all.

EDIT: Here is a link to the distortion: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyVFA.jpg

[image: img]

Comment: you need to add also your matrices ... are you using perspective? what are your `znear zfar` clipping planes? where is your quad and how big it is? you most likely just intersecting clipping planes or are too close to camera fisheing the quad ... Add different color to each corner or texture it so you see if it is cut or just distorted ...

Comment: The source code accompanying https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations may be useful to compare/debug your program...

Comment: What are your projection matrix parameters? znear, zfar, fov, ???

Comment: you should also give us the code you use for your genrating your quads, are you sure you want to rotate around the x axis ? if you do so your quad is going to have a different depth and the perspective distorsion is going to appear

Comment: My projection matrix near and far planes are 0.1 and 600f. My position is -5f on the z everything else 0.

Comment: My fov is 60 degrees. The aspect ratio is width / height. The quad coordinates are `-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
   0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
   0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
   -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f` and the indices are `0, 1, 2,
  0, 3, 2 `

Comment: @TheProff Now I got you. What you see is the perspective projection of the quad. Since the quad is rotated around the x axis, the distance to the bottom points is greater than the distance to the top points. At perspective projection objects become smaller (respectively projected distances become shorter) by the distance to the point of view. Note if an object is far away in the real world it appears "smaller".

Comment: So what would be the steps to fix it, how could I rotate without causing distortion?

Comment: @TheProff What do you want to fix!? That's the behavior of perspective projection. If you don't want the perspective distortion, then you've to use orthographic projection. See [`glm::ortho`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00243.html#ga6615d8a9d39432e279c4575313ecb456).

Comment: This is not just perspective projection distortion, I can tell because when I rotate the shape, the whole thing gets 2-3 times longer in the axis I'm rotating it around. And it also rotates slower when it gets closer to a 90 degree angle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For perspective views its common that shapes are distorted. Your case looks like this:

[image: overview]

The x axis is going through your QUAD center so when you rotate around x half of your quad gets closer to camera and other half gets far ... As you can see the closer part can get much bigger than the size of unrotated QUAD.

The disproportional distortion might be caused by 2 things:

1. **fisheye**

   you are too close to camera try to move your quad further away from camera for example by `10.0` or more units in z axis. The closer you are to znear the bigger the disproportion between closer and far parts of the QUAD

   fisheye is greatly affected by znear and FOV of the camera so changing those might help too ... (bigger znear, smaller FOV)

   I see fisheye like this:

   [image: fisheye]

   if your object is too close to camera then unrotated QUAD is actually smaller then rotated because it has smaller viewing angle between focal point of camera viewing direction (-z axis) and edge of object in ZY plane. Once the camera or QUAD is moved further away from each this will not happen.
2. **wrong aspect ratio correction**

   when you setup your perspective check if you provided correct aspect ration (and not inverted). If the case than the scales on x and y axises are not visually same so when your QUAD is facing camera directly its not square ... and while rotating it could create weird looking behaviour.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I figured out the issue, it turned out that when I was making my perspective projection matrix I forgot to convert my fov to radians, so I essentially had an fov of over 3000 degrees. It worked fine after I fixed that.